# SQL Server 2005 where condition with string comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, string, where-clause

I am using SQL Server 2005 with the following query

```
SELECT * 
FROM EMPLOYEE 
WHERE EMP_NAME = 'ABCD'
```

It gave me the proper results and when i tried the same query with `'ABCD  '`, then also it gave me the same result!!!

I feel it should not give any results as there is no employee with name `'ABCD  '`

Or "WHERE" condition works like this with String comparison?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surprisingly, that's how it works!

[INF: How SQL Server Compares Strings with Trailing Spaces](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626):

> For example, Transact-SQL considers
>   the strings 'abc' and 'abc ' to be
>   equivalent for most comparison
>   operations.

[INF: Behavior of ANSI_PADDING](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154886/EN-US/)